# center div inside div with absolute position using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Other problem center using css, I wish center a div inside other div with absolute position, I want to get a similar result to this image:

[image: expected]

preferably using flexbox, example code:

```css
.abs_1 {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
}

.abs_2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 60px;
  left: 250px;
}

.center{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.center div {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="abs_1">
  <div class="center">
      <div>Hello.</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="abs_2">
  <div class="center">
      <div>World</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I get the following:

[image: wrong]

could you do this using flex css?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution using **[CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)**.

CSS

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.abs_1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px;
    background: red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.abs_2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px;
    background: blue;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.center > div {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">

    <div class="abs_1">
        <div class="center">
            <div>Hello.</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="abs_2">
        <div class="center">
            <div>World</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div><!-- end #container -->
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/3ekyetc0/

Comment: Thought the question was about center a `div` inside other div container  with `position: absolute` not **removable**